# Highcharts add button fix chart

Tags: highcharts

Good day!
How do I add a button to link it to a graph? 
I mean, when I add a button. When I stretch the graph, the button remains at its same coordinates when it should have moved as well.

I add it like this:

```js
chart.renderer.button('Reset', 500, 200, function() {
  console.log(chart);
}, null, null, null).attr({
      zIndex: 4
    }).add();
```

[image]

Comment: Could you prepare an example which shows where this button should be placed/attached? Because now you set fixed values and as I understood, you want to set this button responsive.

Comment: I took a screenshot above. 
I want the buttons to be centered at the bottom.
They will be designed to get closer and further from the schedule.
Now if I change the overall size of the chart, the buttons are shifted, but should remain centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a guideline of how to creates responsive buttons using the render feature.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tj50heo1/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        let chart = this,
          x = chart.plotWidth / 2 + chart.plotLeft,
          y = chart.plotHeight;

        if (chart.customBtn) {
          chart.customBtn.destroy();
        }

        chart.customBtn = chart.renderer.button('Reset', x, y, function() {}, null, null, null).attr({
          zIndex: 4,
        }).add();

        //center button after render with width value
        chart.customBtn.translate(chart.customBtn.x - chart.customBtn.width /2, chart.customBtn.y)
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render